# Is it possible (again) to collect event data from Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I run an event platform and am looking for a way to retrieve event data (name, date, location, description, etc.) from different events (festivals) on Facebook.

We were working on a connection when the Cambridge Analytica thing happened. Since then my developers have not found a new way to retrieve info, but I'm a bit skeptical.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, it is not possible to get Page Events (which you want to get, i assume):

> This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/

Comment: Hi luschn, Thanks for your reply.
I've taken a look at the page you linked. It seems this refers to user events, not festivals. Is that correct. I want to retrieve the info from this example page: https://www.facebook.com/events/932779340242191/
And 1.000 more similar to this page. All official events.

Comment: there are no festivals on facebook, there are just user events and page events. the event in your comment is a page event. access to page events is not possible at this time, as facebook states in the docs. did you try accessing the specific events?